# Fields of Algebraic Elements: Algebraic Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 29, Exercise G5.

> Any complex number which is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$ is called an algebraic number. The set of all the algebraic numbers is a field, which we shall designate by $\Bbb{A}$.
>
> Let $a(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ be in $\Bbb{A}[x]$, and let $c$ be any root of $a(x)$.
>   Note $\Bbb{Q}(a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.
>
> Let $\Bbb{Q}(a_0, \cdots, a_n) = \Bbb{Q}_1$.
>   Since $a(x) \in \Bbb{Q}_1[x], c$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}_1$.
>
> Prove: $c\in\Bbb{A}$

1. Given $c$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}_1$, $\Bbb{Q}_1(c)$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_1$, which in turn is a finite extension
   of $\Bbb{Q}$.  Hence $\Bbb{Q}_1(c)$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.
2. $[\Bbb{Q}_1(c):\Bbb{Q}] = [\Bbb{Q}_1(c):\Bbb{Q}_1][\Bbb{Q}_1:\Bbb{Q}]$.
   This implies the existence of a minimal polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ such that $c$
   is a root.  Hence $c$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$ and therefore $c\in\Bbb{A}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. I would, however, rewrite your points 1 and 2 into a fluid argument. If $c$ is algebraic over some field then it is certainly an element of $\mathbb{A}$

Comment: Lookin' good to me!